# Masking a CAShapeLayer creates this weird artifact?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uibezierpath

I want to create a smooth progress bar for a to-do list. I used a circle (CGMutablePath) that masks the gray area and there's an obvious arc-like artifact. Not only that but there's also an artifact on the right side of the bar.

Note: I tried to rasterize the layers to no avail.

What causes iOS to do this and how can I smooth this out or get rid of it?

```
private var circleMask: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    backgroundColor = GradientColor(.leftToRight, frame: self.bounds, colors: GradientFlatRed())
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
    plainProgressBar.layer.cornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    plainProgressBar.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    plainProgressBar.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    createMask()


}

private func createMask() {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x+25/2, y: bounds.origin.y+25/2), radius: 25/2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: false)
    path.addRect(bounds)
    circleMask.path = path
    circleMask.backgroundColor = plainMeterColor.cgColor
    circleMask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    plainProgressBar.layer.mask = circleMask
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why you're doing this. You can get exactly the effect you want by using a UIProgressView with a stretchable custom progress image.

Comment: I think I should have worded it a little better haha. Not a progress bar as in to download something; I mean a progress bar as in checking off a To-Do list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is clearly an error in composition of the antialiased edges.

Knee-jerk question: do you have an atypical blend mode set?

Easiest solution: don't use `path.addArc` and `path.addRect` to generate two completely distinct shapes. Just use one of the `init(roundedRect:...` methods and set a corner radius of half your height, stretching the total path beyond the available space to the left to create a hard edge.

Or, if that doesn't appear, construct the path manually as a `move`, `addLine(to:`, `addArc` of only half a circle, then a final `addLine(to:` and a `close`. E.g. (thoroughly untested, especially re: start and end angles and clockwise versus anticlockwise versus iOS's upside-down coordinate system)

```
private func createMask() {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x+25/2, y: 0))
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x+25/2, y: bounds.origin.y+25/2), radius: 25/2, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2.0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*3.0/2.0), clockwise: false)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 25))
    path.close()
    ...
```

Comment: keep in mind, I need to have the circle to mask the left part of the gray area to create the illusion of progress (like above). If not, it'll just be the gray area minus the circle. That `kCAFillRuleEvenOdd' value removes that gray area. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @rockyraccoon all suggestions contained in the post *retain* the circle.

Comment: Sample code posted, hopefully to satisfy the down voter. It's a pretty simple concept: if an edge is visible where shapes overlays another, don't draw two shapes. Draw one shape that has the same outline. I've no idea how that's a controversial proposition so please let me know how I've managed to communicate that poorly.