# Same cornerRadius is visible underneath the view

Tags: swift, uiview, core-graphics

If I place to `UIViews` with the same `cornerRadius` on top of each other, I can see the bottom (red) view near the corners of the top (yellow) view. Is it possible to fix it?

```
let rectFrame = CGRect(x:50, y:100, width: 150, height: 150)
let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10.0

let redView = UIView(frame:rectFrame)
redView.backgroundColor = .red
redView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

let yellowView = UIView(frame: rectFrame)
yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellow
yellowView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

view.addSubview(redView)
view.addSubview(yellowView)
```

[image]

The corner (zoomed):

[image]

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187945/masking-a-cashapelayer-creates-this-weird-artifact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a result of *antialiasing*. Both views have some semitransparent pixels comprising the curve. It makes the curve look smooth even though it isn’t (because pixels are square).

You could [turn off antialiasing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1621285-allowsedgeantialiasing) for the drawing of the layers, but I’d advise against that. It would be simpler to make the rear view invisible.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so that it is something to do with antialiasing, but interestingly setting on both layers `allowsEdgeAntialiasing = false` doesn't make any difference

Comment: No, you probably can’t override it except by turning it off for the whole app, and they probably don’t allow that anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the zposition of the nodes to different values so that you control which one is at the top..

Comment: Do you mean setting `yellowView.layer.zPosition = 1`? If so, it doesn't help

Comment: And redView.zPosition should be less than yellowView.zPosition

Comment: Yep, redview zPosition is 0